# AppleScript find folder with specific file

Tags: macos, applescript

I have a folder with file `/resources/video.mov`. This folder with video can located in any place, like `/Users/UserName/Desktop/resources/video.mov` or `/Applications/resources/video.mov` and etc. I need to find this folder with video and copy to specific place. I can't find  path of folder with video to copy it.

```
tell application "Finder"
    duplicate items in folder "_locatedPath_" to folder "_destiontionPath_" with replacing
end tell
```

Comment: If you don't know the location the shell commands `find` or `mdfind` are your friend. Vanilla AppleScript is too slow.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me using the latest version of Sierra

Change the value of variable `destinationFolder` to the output folder of your choice

```
property theContainer : missing value
property containingFolder : "resources" -- change if needed
property theSearch : "video.mov" -- change if needed
property destinationFolder : (path to desktop as text) -- change if needed

set findFile to do shell script "mdfind -name " & theSearch 

repeat with i from 1 to number of paragraphs in findFile
    set this_item to POSIX file (paragraph i of findFile) as alias
    tell application "Finder"
        if name of this_item is theSearch then
            set theContainer to the container of this_item as text
            if theContainer contains containingFolder then
                set resultObject to duplicate this_item ¬
                    to destinationFolder ¬
                    replacing true ¬
                    routing suppressed true ¬
                    with exact copy
            end if
        end if
    end tell
end repeat
```

Comment: It is unclear to me if the OP only wants to duplicate “video.mov” or all of the contents of the containing folder of “video.mov” (which would be “resources”) to the destination folder.  I'm assuming the OP is just looking to duplicate “video.mov” which is located in “resources” folder.

Comment: Somethings to consider: Open Finder's dictionary in Script Editor and search for `POSIX`, you won't find it. `set this_item to POSIX file this_item as alias` should not be within the `tell application "Finder"` _block_ because `Finder` actually can't `set this_item to POSIX file this_item as alias` and it actually silently errors out with `--> error number -1728 from POSIX file ...`. It should be outside of that block. However, you also do not need `property fileList : {}` and `copy findFile to fileList`. Look at this [reworked example of your code](https://paste.ee/p/6IKdE)

Comment: The `fileList` returned from `do shell script "mdfind -name " & theSearch` is already paragraphs of POSIX pathnames, so get rid of `set this_item to POSIX file this_item as alias` and change `set this_item to paragraph i of fileList` to `set this_item to POSIX file (paragraph i of fileList) as alias`. Additionally `set fileList to do shell script "mdfind -name " & theSearch` handles filenames with or without spaces because you are aliasing them back to an HFS+ path for Finder to work with.

Comment: Not sure why you're getting that result but the reworked example of your code works without issue on my system as I recoded it. [Here's the output run with and without as space in the name.](https://paste.ee/p/O6vc0) BTW `log theContainer` was supposed to be removed before I posted the code, so obviously it's not needed, I was just verifying something. :)

Comment: BTW Very good rework of your original answer, which you deleted. +1

Comment: Thanks dude:-)  I think I figured out why it was not working for me with mdfind -name...  I had script editor just create a new file with extension (mov) ... video.mov.  The result was An empty file "video.mov" With zero zero information and 0 bytes..  Alternately I used a different file for mdfind And it works correctly. Thanks for the scrutinizing :-)